# indesign cs5 numbered lists not sequencing

Tags: adobe-indesign

I am trying to create a paragraph style for number lists.  Pretty basic, just some customized indents etc.  But each item in my list is not sequentially numbered, i.e., each item starts with 1.

Please advise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't directly involve code, nor tools used primarily for programming You'll probably have a greater chance of getting an answer to your question over at [graphicdesign.stackexchange.com](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/). It has similar questions as yours tagged under [adobe-indesign](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adobe-indesign).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at "Numbering style" option ?
[image]

In my french version, "Suite…" means increment previous number. And "Commencer…" means "Starts at…"

Comment: In mine, that option means that it should start numbering from the previous numbered list.  Which means it may be starting from 6, or 13, etc.  Interestingly, when that option is selected, the number increments properly.  It just doesn't start at 1 for each list.